# Trouble running a bash host script on ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

My colleague wrote a script to display the hostnames of IP addresses in our network that I need to notate. The issue is that I have confirmed that the script works on CentOS with no problem. I don't have access to an unrestricted CentOS box at this minute so I'm stuck with command line Ubuntu with the sandbox here at work. For some reason the same script won't work and wondering if someone can point me in the right direction?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ipranges="
173.225.176

127.0.0
"

for r in $ipranges; do
    for i in `seq 1 255`; do
        host $r.$i|grep -vi 'not found'
    done
done
```

I also tried changing the shebang line to /bin/bash as well and no luck. The error that I'm currently getting is the following using Ubuntu:

Output:

```
$ sh script.sh

socket.cL1915: internal_send: 0.0.0.1#53: invalid argument
```

If anyone needs to know this is so we can notate what IP's are being used to submit a report to ARIN, in case this knowledge is required. Thanks for any help anyone can provide me!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying on?

Comment: I can not reproduce the error with: Unbuntu 11.04, Unbuntu 14.04 and RHEL 6.

Comment: Yes, I'm using:Ubuntu 3.13.0-35-generic, Distrib relase = 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the empty line in your `ipranges` variable. The expression `host $r.$i` seems to expand to `host .1`, which appears to be interpreted as `0.0.0.1` by your *host* implementation. (Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this on my boxes, but it seems to be a plausible explaination.)

Try either omitting the empty line, or better: writing all IP addresses in one, or even better: use a proper [bash array](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop-array/) (but then you shoul explicitely use `/bin/bash` as shebang).

Comment: Hm, any free shells or jailshell access you know of where I may be able to sign up and run this script on that you know of? If not, I'll try your suggestions or another box perhaps.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Have you tried rewriting the script as I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering the problem is that while single quotes may work, it seems that back ticks are what is truly required. I followed the advice of this article here:

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130805103907AAQ5CGh

Basically, exchanges the single quotes in my for statement for back ticks and works like a charm. Thanks for all those who did try to help!